# Does Doxylamine have any Influence on the Monoaminergic System?

Tags: biochemistry, neurotransmitter

Does doxylamine have any affects on the monoaminergic system? Specifically I am interested in adrenergic or serotonergic activity but additional information on its dopaminergic activity won't hurt either.